# Python regex non greedy not matching substring when the pattern has string surrounding the variable part

Tags: python, regex, regex-greedy

I hate to  post  such specific questions as why a regex is not working, but I have been searching for someone with the same problem to no avail. It seems I am miss understanding something about  greedy regex:

I am using python for this:

```
input_string = "tt_firstbutnotlast_tt_second_tt"
pattern1 = "(tt.+tt)?"
```

I want to match the "*second*" part, but even with the "?"  It always matches the whole string. I thought "?" would make it match the smallest string that can match it. Can  someone explain to me what I am miss understanding about the greedy part?

note: I simplified the string example to make it more clear

Comment: You need ``pattern1 = r'\\b(?:(?!\\b)[^:])*:\\b'``

Comment: it shoul work with a `input_string.split("tt")` with this example, can you give a more detailled explination on your requirements.

Comment: Use `.*(tt.*tt)`